# flutter constant appbar on different screen navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing an app in flutter with few screen I want to add AppBar in home screen and want that appbar to be fixed in all screen, but in the dummy code which i have written the complete screen is getting replaced by that.

Below is the screen
HomeScreen - here i have created appbar

[image]

When I click on AddPolicy Button, i get that screen where right now i just have a text but the complete screen gets replaced as below, but I want the header appBar should be fixed. How can I achieve this.

Below is the code
homepage - https://github.com/lodha13/samkit/blob/main/lib/screens/home.dart

AddPolicy page - https://github.com/lodha13/samkit/blob/main/lib/screens/add_policy.dart

[image]

Comment: You need to create a widget for app bar and use everywhere you want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two opptions:

1. have a global widget for `appbar` and use it on each different page,
   or
2. You can have one `Scaffold` in your `main.dart` and instead of generating a new one for each page, only change the `body` parameter using `setState`. for example:

```
// have as many widget as you want for each page
const body1 = Text("body1"); //just a simple example, you can change it to whatever you want. 
const body2 = Text("body2");
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      ),
      body: handleBody(selectedIndex)
    );
```

then you can have a function to handle bodies:

```
handleBody(int index){ // you can pass different input for body selection I have used an int for simplicity

if(index == 1){return body1;}
if(index ==2) {return body2;}
// and so on
}
```

now with changing the `selectedIndex` you can show different bodies. Personally, I prefer to have a `list` of `widgets` and select one of them based on `selectedIndex`.

Comment: This will be easy if there is one level of navigation, is there a standard way when i have nested level of navigation like home ->screen1 -> screen2 and so on. But my app bar remain same? I can create appbar in each screen but that is bad. and do i need to create it as stateful widget to invoke setState

Comment: yes, you can, note that I have suggested two solutions, the first one needs to have an `appbar` and use it in each screen (that you do not want). But the second solution uses a trick to do not create a new page and also routing. it would handle all functionality in one file and it is suitable for small projects.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend going through this tutorial by Flutter: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#7

It pretty much addresses your problem on top. In the tutorial, they kept the same NavigationRail. In the NavigationRail they [set selected Index](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/main/namer/step_08/lib/main.dart#L87-L90) which changes [page](https://github.com/flutter/codelabs/blob/main/namer/step_08/lib/main.dart#L58-L68).

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget page;
    switch (selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavoritesPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }
}
```